# Part of web crawler

Tags: java, web-scraping

According to the first part: [Forum crawler - counts statistics for words in chosen forum topic](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/174965/forum-crawler-counts-statistics-for-words-in-chosen-forum-topic/174983?noredirect=1#comment332096_174983)
I take into account the review of Janos and created Iterator for my classes.

This is part of the whole App. I have a problem with dividing it into classes, I'm not sure about this architecture which I've provided.

**Descirption:**

`Topic` is the specific topic of the forum
`Page` is the page of the forum
The aim of this code is to iterate through pages in `Topic` and create `Page` for every page.

**The code**

```
// example of use:
public class AppMain{
public static void main(String[] args){
                String url = "https://4programmers.net/Forum/Newbie/210891-od_czego_zaczac_nauke_programowania";
        Topic topic = new Topic(url);

        PageIterator it = topic.iterator();
        //it.next();
        Page page = it.next();
}
}
```

...

```
/*
 * to consider: what if the view of the post will be changed from 10 to 50?
 */
public class Topic implements Iterable<Page> {

    private String urlBase;    // URL of the topic on forum
    private String pagePattern; // pattern whcich change while changing page number of the topic, for example: ?page=
    private PageIteratorEnum pageIteratorType; // type of the forum 4programmers? Codercity? etc.

    // to consider: put these variables into abstract class?

    public Topic(String url, String pagePattern) {
        this.urlBase = url;
        this.pagePattern = pagePattern;
    }

    public Topic(String url) {
        this.urlBase = url;
        this.pagePattern = "?page=";
    }

    public void setUrlBase(String html) {
        this.urlBase = html;
    }

    public String getUrlBase() {
        return urlBase;
    }

    public void setPagePattern(String pattern) {
        pagePattern = pattern;
    }

    public String getPagePattern() {
        return pagePattern;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return getUrlBase();
    }

    public void setIterator(PageIteratorEnum type){
        pageIteratorType = type;
    }

    @Override
    public PageIterator iterator() {
        if(pageIteratorType == null){
            throw new RuntimeException("First set iterator type by setIterator() method.");
        }
        return new PageIteratorFactoryImp1(this).produceIterator(pageIteratorType);
    }
}
```

...

```
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;

public class Page {

    Document doc;

    public Page(Document doc){
        this.doc = doc;
    }
}
```

...

```
import java.util.Iterator;

public interface PageIterator extends Iterator<Page>{

    public boolean hasNext();

    public Page next();
}
```

...

```
public enum PageIteratorEnum {

    it4PROGRAMMERS, itCODERCITY;
}
```

...

```
public interface PageIteratorFactory {

    public PageIterator produceIterator(PageIteratorEnum type);
}
```

...

```
public class PageIteratorFactoryImp1 implements PageIteratorFactory{

    Topic topic;

    public PageIteratorFactoryImp1(Topic topic){
        this.topic = topic;
    }

    public PageIterator produceIterator(PageIteratorEnum type){
        if(type.equals("it4PROGRAMMERS")){
            return new TopicPageIterator4programmers(topic);
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

...

```
import java.io.IOException;

import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;

public class TopicPageIterator4programmers implements PageIterator {

    private Topic topic;
    private int count = 0;
    String urlBase;
    String pagePattern;
    String browser = "Mozilla/5.0";
    NavigatePanel navigation;

    public TopicPageIterator4programmers(Topic topic) {
        this.topic = topic;
        this.urlBase = topic.getUrlBase();
        this.pagePattern = topic.getPagePattern();
        this.navigation = new NavigatePanel4programmers(urlBase, pagePattern);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasNext() {
        return ((count + 1) <= navigation.getMaxPageNumber());
    }

    @Override
    public Page next() {
        Page result = null;
        String newUrl = urlBase + pagePattern + String.valueOf(++count);
        Document doc = null;
        try {
            doc = Jsoup.connect(newUrl).userAgent(browser).get();
            result = new Page4programmers(doc, count);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("something went wrong with downloading the page: " + newUrl);
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return result;

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

If this code is on github, it would be useful to link to it.

Your `main` does much less than I would expect. The advantage of implementing iterable is so you can concisely express something like this:

```
for (Page page : new Topic(url)) {
    // do stuff with page
}
```

It seems reasonable to me that you might pass Topic both a website url and a class that knows about structure of that site's urls.

I wouldn't expose setters & getters for urlBase & pagePattern until some unit test forces you to do so. Based on the `for` loop above, it's not obvious to me that caller would ever need to interact with Topic, since it's just a means to an end, which is obtaining Pages. Oh, I see, down in the iterator you're wishing for lots of access, sigh.

Exposing setIterator() does not seem like a wise API choice, as the ctor should have dealt with that. But it doesn't, so surely broken `main` throws an exception? Making this CR post off-topic?

It seems that Page is *such* a thin layer over Document that we could dispense with it and just have Topic directly interact with jsoup.

PageIterator could include a better explanation of what code is actually responsible for downloads.

This is perverse:

```
    if (type.equals("it4PROGRAMMERS")) {
```

Having gone to the trouble of creating an identifier, you may as well supply it, rather than a string.

TopicPageIterator4programmers does not obey the robots.txt protocol.
You might consult https://github.com/crawler-commons/crawler-commons and use their support for parsing robots.txt. You should definitely sleep for a second or so between GETs.

These lines that vacuum up the contents of a topic

```
    this.topic = topic;
    this.urlBase = topic.getUrlBase();
    this.pagePattern = topic.getPagePattern();
```

suggest you may have wanted to initially communicate parameters to another class.

For the temp variable newUrl, a name of `url` would suffice. That one line of code, which knows how to construct well-formed URLs for the site, appears to be all that is unique about this class, compared with a class you might write tomorrow that scrapes some other site.

```
        e.printStackTrace();
```

You swallowed the exception. It would be better to let a checked exception bubble up the stack, or to re-throw `e` as a RuntimeException, so it's easy for callers to use your API without fear of accidental NPE.

I recommend you add support for a 2nd website, and then ruthlessly refactor 
so you have as few lines of source code as possible. Write a javadoc comment at the top of each class explaining what the class is responsible for. Significantly, this will help you to keep random lines of code *out* of the class, lines or attributes that clearly don't fall under the sentence explaining the class' responsibility. Also, if you write "this class is responsible for (1) FOO *and* also for (2) BAR" then you'll know it's time to break it apart. Single responsibility, do one thing well.

Comment: Yes, this will be doing something like this whaa ya've written.